# Ruby: How to capture and resolve undefined method when requiring a subclass file

Tags: ruby, dsl

There is a DSL ruby file which I need to parse. It looks like

```rb
# file B.rb
class B < A
  hello "John"
end

hello "Mary"
```

It calls function `hello()` with a string parameter both inside and outside of the class `B`.

I try to `require` the file `B.rb` and resolve the missing methods:

```rb
# file A.rb

# define a class A for subclassing, before loading B.rb
class A
end

# Try to catch the missing methods
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  puts "tried to handle unknown method %s" % name # name is a symbol
end

require("./B.rb")
```

After running this code, the `method_missing` causes infinite loop.

How to capture and resolve undefined method both inside and outside of the class `B`? I want to know what the methods and parameters are called in the DSL file.

Comment: When I run this code, Ruby spits out a `warning: redefining Object#method_missing may cause infinite loop`. So maybe this is just ... expected? There are alternative ways to expose your DSL to the toplevel ... for example you could `instance_eval` its contents within a particular scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hinted at this approach in my comment, but thought it might be useful to spell out.

So first of all we need to define the `method_missing` on something, we can't define it at the toplevel because we'll get this warning

> redefining Object#method_missing may cause infinite loop

Instead, we'll define it on `class A` (at the class level).

```
# in a.rb

class A
  def self.method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    puts "tried to handle unknown method %s" % name # name is a symbol
  end
end
```

Now we can use `class_eval` to evaluate `b.rb` in the scope of `class A` like so:

```
# also in a.rb

A.class_eval(File.read("./b.rb"))
```

Now the "top level" `hello "Mary"` call is actually being executed in the class scope of `A` (where the `method_missing` definition is active). Furthermore, since `class B` inherits from `A`, it also has the `method_missing` definition on the class level, so the `hello "John"` call would hit it as well.

So running the script, I see `tried to handle unknown method hello` printed twice, as expected.

I should note, I don't think it's a good idea to just "ignore" errors in this way ... most likely it's better to halt the execution of the program. But perhaps you have something in mind that requires it, I can't know for sure.

Comment: How do I know what the context/scope the method is in when handling the `method_missing` (in class B or top level in `B.rb`)? I need to parse them differently.

Comment: You could reference `self` in there ... it will return `A` for the "top level", and `A::B` for the other one ...

Comment: Remember, when you inherit like `class B < class A` ... you are basically coping all of `A`'s methods onto `B`, which is why `self` can be something other than `A`, even if the method was originally defined on `A`. For more flexibillity, you can use a module instead and mix it in wherever needed

Comment: I have one more question: if the `class B` calls a function already defined, but passes wrong number of arguments, what is the handler to catch that?

Comment: There aren't special handler methods for every error type. You'd need to use a regular `rescue` for that.

Answer (score 2):

This line in your `method_missing`,

```
puts "tried to handle unknown method %s" % name # name is a symbol
```

results in a call to `to_ary` which is not defined and winds up calling `method_missing` again. Hence your infinite loop.

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  p name
  puts "tried to handle unknown method %s" % name # name is a symbol
end
```

```
# =>
...
...
:to_ary
:to_ary
:to_ary
/System/Library/.../kernel_require.rb:55: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

The fix is pretty simple if you want to do it this way. Use string interpolation.

```
puts "tried to handle unknown method #{name.to_s}"
```

```
# =>
Tried to handle unknown method hello
Tried to handle unknown method hello
```